# Why are pure virtual methods not overridden from a different inheritance branch?

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-functions, linearization

I have this, maybe a little bit complex class hierarchy:

```
class BS {
  public:
    virtual void meth()=0;
};

class BCA : public virtual BS {
};

class BSS : public virtual BS {
};

class BCS : public virtual BCA, public virtual BSS {
};

class BI4 {
  public:
    void meth() {};
};

class BT4 : public virtual BI4, public virtual BSS {
};

class T4 : public virtual BCS, public virtual BT4 {
};

int main() {
  T4 t4;
};
```

Now the problem is that although the `void meth()` is available in the inheritance graph, despite this code won't compile:

```
$ g++ -c t.cc -std=c++11
t.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cc:27:6: error: cannot declare variable ‘t4’ to be of abstract type ‘T4’
   T4 t4;
      ^
t.cc:23:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘T4’:
 class T4 : public virtual BCS, public virtual BT4 {
       ^
t.cc:3:18: note:        virtual void BS::meth()
     virtual void meth()=0;
                  ^
t.cc:3:18: note:        virtual void BS::meth()
```

It seems to me as if `BS` somehow wouldn't see the overloaded `meth()` method through the BS->BCA->BCS->T4->BT4->BI4 chain.
But why? The method is clearly available, the C3 linearization algorithm used by the C++ should be able very clearly find it.

Comment: Nitpick: you mean "overridden" not "overloaded".

Comment: The multiple `virtual` inheritance relationships are a bit of overkill. You only need that for base class sub-objects that would otherwise occur two or more times.

Comment: "little bit complex" o.O It wouldn't be quite so bad maybe if the names were in any way sensible.

Comment: _"the BS->BCA->BCS->T4->BT4->BI4 chain"_ goes up then comes down; that's not how it works!

Comment: While you can't do this, you can still delegate to BI4 (even to T in a template).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Other C3 linearization languages/frameworks do this seamlessly, f.e. see the [dojo](https://dojotoolkit.org) Javascript framework.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Uhm, sorry. I wanted to give a sanitized example, the pure logical problem, without the implementation details (you can check the whole code [here](https://github.com/HorvathAkosPeter/pipenet/tree/master/posxx)).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Agreed, I've made a class hierarchy graph with doxygen and minimized the virtual inheritances to the diamonds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main aspects:

- A given class can only override member functions from its base classes.
  Since your `BI4` class doesn't have `BS` as a base class, it can't override anything from `BS`.
- It's possible to *inherit in an implementation* of a pure virtual function defined in a virtual base class, much like in Java, but the class providing that implementation must itself also have that virtual base class.

Example:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

#ifdef GOOD
    struct Impl_foo: virtual Base
    {
        void foo() override {}
    };
#else
    struct Impl_foo
    {
        virtual void foo() {}
    };
#endif

struct Abstract_derived: virtual Base
{};

struct Derived
    : Abstract_derived
    , Impl_foo      // Java-like implementation inheritance.
                    // In C++ called "by dominance".
{};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    Derived o;
    o.foo();
}
```

Without defining the `GOOD` macro symbol, this code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 5):

The rules of the language don't allow it. A virtual function can only be overridden by the declaration of a function with the same name and parameters in a derived class. Since `BI4` isn't derived from `BS`, `BI4::meth` cannot override `BS::meth`. If a class inherits (directly or indirectly) from both `BS` and `BI4`, then it inherits *two* functions called `meth`: one from `BS`, still abstract and not overridden, and one from `BI4`.

Answer (score 2):

`BI4` does not inherit from `BS` either directly or indirectly, so its method `BI4::meth()` is entirely unrelated and cannot override `BS::meth()`.

You can only override methods from base classes, not from "sibling" or "uncle" classes.